# How does a voltage controller (outer loop) set the current reference for the (inner) current loop in cascaded control of a boost-converter?

Tags: control, boost

I am currently trying to understand the cascaded current-voltage control of a boost converter (and later design the PI-controller). Let me summarize the information I have collected so far:

Outer (voltage) control loop:

- Input: Difference between voltage set point and measured voltage
- Used to control the output voltage of converter
- Sets **current reference** for inner (current) control loop
- Controller type: PI

Inner (current) control loop:

- Input: Difference between measured inductor current and **reference current**
- Used to regulate the inductor current
- Has to be at least three times faster than outer control loop
- Error current is processed by the controller to adjust the duty cycle
- Controller type: PI

**My question is now:** How is the output of the voltage controller converted into a current reference signal (explanation needed)?

My only idea is that the relationship between the voltage and current is based on the boost converters transfer function G: I_ref = G * V.
For tuning the PI-controller I will follow this tutorial: https://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/cascade-digital-pid-control-design-for-power-electronic-converters.html. But, I can not see here that they have used the boost converters transfer function to get the reference current.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Current-mode- and voltage-mode-controlled converters (CM or VM) differ in the way the control variable \$D\$ is elaborated. Check this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660684/idea-behind-current-mode-control-in-dc-dc-converter) I gave on SE. With VM, you *directly* set the duty ratio \$D\$ while in CM, the outer loop programs the peak inductor current and *indirectly* the duty ratio. It's the error amplifier which programs the peak current sense voltage at the current sense comparator input. When the inductor current reaches the setpoint the power switch turns off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also found another nice explanation here: https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/how-to-use-current-mode-control-in-dc-dc-converters. If I got it right, the outer loop creates a reference voltage (desired - measured voltage). This error voltage is compared in the inner loop to the difference of the reference voltage minus the inductor current (which is in turn a voltage measured by a shunt resistor).

Comment: There are plenty of papers and articles on the subject. You can have a look at my [APEC 2019](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202019.pdf) seminar but also download my free [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) to simulate a buck converter operated in VM or CM. Most of the files work on the free demo of SIMPLIS.

Comment: Do you agree with my explanation so far?

Comment: The error voltage from the outer loop is a setpoint to force the inductor peak current read through a sensing element: the switch remains closed until the inductor current reaches the value imposed by the voltage loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That finally makes everything clear.