Current mode control or voltage mode control of flyback converters
What is used more nowadays - current mode or voltage mode control when considering flyback converters?

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660684/idea-behind-current-mode-control-in-dc-dc-converter/660695#660695

I would say that the vast majority of flyback controllers are using current-mode control (CM) while some manufacturers - like POWI for instance - use voltage-mode control (VM) for years, starting with their TOPswitches in the 90's. The pros and cons between the two are summarized in the link provided by G36.

Both. You are almost always going to want current-mode control for the internal MOSFET PWM loop. And a voltage-mode regulation loop wrapped around that. There are exceptions that will depend on the application and tradeoffs. For example, If your running open loop, you won't need the voltage feedback. This will save cost at the expense of poor voltage regulation. That may be acceptable if the load is very tolerant of voltage supply.
